# Delete blank entries in CSV file Python

Tags: python, csv

I need to read in a CSV file, from Excel, whose rows may be an arbitrary length.

The problem is the python retains these blank entries, but need to delete them for a future algorithm. Below is the output, I don't want the blank entries.

```
     ['5', '1', '5', '10', '4', '']
     ['3', '1', '5', '10', '2', '']
     ['6', '1', '5', '10', '5', '2']
     ['9', '10', '5', '10', '7', '']
     ['8', '5', '5', '10', '7', '']
     ['1', '1', '5', '10', '', '']
     ['2', '1', '5', '10', '1', '']
     ['7', '1', '5', '10', '6', '4']
     ['4', '1', '5', '10', '3', '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list comprehension integrated with the `csv` library:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    result = [[item for item in row if item != ''] for row in reader]

print result
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about as verbose a function as I could write to do what you want.  There are certainly slicker ways.

```
def remove_blanks(a_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in a_list:
        if item != "":
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension version:

```
a = ['5', '1', '5', '10', '4', '']

[x for x in a if x != '']
Out[19]: ['5', '1', '5', '10', '4']
```

You may be better served by filtering at the csv read step instead.